# Handling API JSON Response Exceptions

Tags: python, json, list, exception, python-requests

How to handle missing data in JSON responses?
I'm trying to get data from a website's API in order to append it into a list and later on insert it into a SQL Database. My issue is that some values aren't always in the response body and this raises an error when I try to append it into a list.
API request and adding the response's json to a variable named "data" (the API KEY and secret are a free test user available for anyone) :

```
import requests
import pyodbc

url = 'https://app.omie.com.br/developer/api-test/?url=https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/mf/&OMIE_APP_KEY=38333295000&OMIE_APP_SECRET=4cea520a0e2a2ecdc267b75d3424a0ed&OMIE_CALL=ListarMovimentos'
test1 = {
  "nPagina": 1,
  "nRegPorPagina": 500
}

res = requests.post(url, json=test1)
data = res.json()
```

The JSON Response (Not all of it as it's pretty big):
The data I need is in `response`->`movimentos`->`detalhes`

```
{
    "information": {
        "url": "https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/financas/mf/",
        "content_type": "application/json; encoding=UTF-8",
        "http_code": 200,
        "header_size": 529,
        "request_size": 270,
        "filetime": -1,
        "ssl_verify_result": 0,
        "redirect_count": 0,
        "total_time": 6.309164,
        "namelookup_time": 2.7e-5,
        "connect_time": 0.001066,
        "pretransfer_time": 0.018146,
        "size_upload": 143,
        "size_download": 221588,
        "speed_download": 35122,
        "speed_upload": 22,
        "download_content_length": 221588,
        "upload_content_length": 143,
        "starttransfer_time": 6.303321,
        "redirect_time": 0,
        "redirect_url": "",
        "primary_ip": "52.67.79.140",
        "certinfo": [],
        "primary_port": 443,
        "local_ip": "10.0.5.217",
        "local_port": 54770
    },
    "request": {
        "call": "ListarMovimentos",
        "app_key": "38333295000",
        "app_secret": "4cea******************a0ed",
        "param": [
            {
                "nPagina": 1,
                "nRegPorPagina": 500
            }
        ]
    },
    "response_header": [
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r",
        "Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2021 18:43:18 GMT\r",
        "Content-Type: application/json; encoding=UTF-8\r",
        "Content-Length: 221588\r",
        "Connection: keep-alive\r",
        "Server: nginx\r",
        "X-Omie-Request-Id: 03c78330-59bd-11eb-bc89-791b8d1252d3\r",
        "Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT\r",
        "Last-Modified: Mon, 18 Jan 2021 18:43:18 GMT\r",
        "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0\r",
        "Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0\r",
        "Pragma: no-cache\r",
        "Vary: Accept-Encoding\r",
        "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload\r",
        "\r",
        ""
    ],
    "response": {
        "nPagina": 1,
        "nTotPaginas": 9,
        "nRegistros": 500,
        "nTotRegistros": 4336,
        "movimentos": [
            {
                "detalhes": {
                    "cCPFCNPJCliente": "24.111.930/0001-80",
                    "cCodCateg": "1.01.02",
                    "cGrupo": "PREVISAO_CONTRATO",
                    "cNatureza": "R",
                    "cNumCtr": "2020/01001",
                    "cNumParcela": "001/001",
                    "cOperacao": "01",
                    "cOrigem": "VENR",
                    "cStatus": "PREVISAO",
                    "cTipo": "99999",
                    "dDtEmissao": "30/10/2021",
                    "dDtPrevisao": "04/11/2021",
                    "dDtVenc": "04/11/2021",
                    "nCodCC": 1208238,
                    "nCodCliente": 2370765,
                    "nCodCtr": 462539320,
                    "nCodTitulo": 300462539320001,
                    "nValorTitulo": 3302
                }
            },
            {
                "detalhes": {
                    "cCPFCNPJCliente": "24.111.930/0001-80",
                    "cCodCateg": "1.01.02",
                    "cGrupo": "PREVISAO_CONTRATO",
                    "cNatureza": "R",
                    "cNumCtr": "2020/01001",
                    "cNumParcela": "001/001",
                    "cOperacao": "01",
                    "cOrigem": "VENR",
                    "cStatus": "PREVISAO",
                    "cTipo": "99999",
                    "dDtEmissao": "30/11/2021",
                    "dDtPrevisao": "05/12/2021",
                    "dDtVenc": "05/12/2021",
                    "nCodCC": 1208238,
                    "nCodCliente": 2370765,
                    "nCodCtr": 462539320,
                    "nCodTitulo": 300462539320001,
                    "nValorTitulo": 3302
                }
            },
            {
                "detalhes": {
                    "cCPFCNPJCliente": "24.111.930/0001-80",
                    "cCodCateg": "1.01.02",
                    "cGrupo": "PREVISAO_CONTRATO",
                    "cNatureza": "R",
                    "cNumCtr": "2020/01001",
                    "cNumParcela": "001/001",
                    "cOperacao": "01",
                    "cOrigem": "VENR",
                    "cStatus": "PREVISAO",
                    "cTipo": "99999",
                    "dDtEmissao": "30/12/2021",
                    "dDtPrevisao": "04/01/2022",
                    "dDtVenc": "04/01/2022",
                    "nCodCC": 1208238,
                    "nCodCliente": 2370765,
                    "nCodCtr": 462539320,
                    "nCodTitulo": 300462539320001,
                    "nValorTitulo": 3302
                }
            },
            {
                "detalhes": {
                    "cCPFCNPJCliente": "24.111.930/0001-80",
                    "cCodCateg": "1.01.02",
                    "cGrupo": "PREVISAO_CONTRATO",
                    "cNatureza": "R",
                    "cNumCtr": "2020/01001",
                    "cNumParcela": "001/001",
                    "cOperacao": "01",
                    "cOrigem": "VENR",
                    "cStatus": "PREVISAO",
                    "cTipo": "99999",
                    "dDtEmissao": "30/01/2022",
                    "dDtPrevisao": "04/02/2022",
                    "dDtVenc": "04/02/2022",
                    "nCodCC": 1208238,
                    "nCodCliente": 2370765,
                    "nCodCtr": 462539320,
                    "nCodTitulo": 300462539320001,
                    "nValorTitulo": 3302
                }
            },
            {
                "detalhes": {
                    "cCPFCNPJCliente": "24.111.930/0001-80",
                    "cCodCateg": "1.01.02",
                    "cGrupo": "PREVISAO_CONTRATO",
                    "cNatureza": "R",
                    "cNumCtr": "2020/01001",
                    "cNumParcela": "001/001",
                    "cOperacao": "01",
                    "cOrigem": "VENR",
                    "cStatus": "PREVISAO",
                    "cTipo": "99999",
                    "dDtEmissao": "28/02/2022",
                    "dDtPrevisao": "05/03/2022",
                    "dDtVenc": "05/03/2022",
                    "nCodCC": 1208238,
                    "nCodCliente": 2370765,
                    "nCodCtr": 462539320,
                    "nCodTitulo": 300462539320001,
                    "nValorTitulo": 3302
                    "dDtRegistro": "19/02/2014",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The data that am able to itinerate over as it is response mandatory:

```
for i in data['response']['movimentos']:
    lista_cod.extend(i['detalhes']['cCodCateg'])
```

The data I can't properly itinerate over as it is not always in the response body, as I tried to handle:

```
for i in data['response']['movimentos']:
    try:
        lista_datas.extend(i['detalhes']['dDtRegistro'])
    except:
        lista_datas.extend('')
```

I also tried to `extend`it as `None`unsucessfully. I get the list as result:

```
['2', '2', '/', '0', '1', '/', '2', '0', '2', '0', '2', '1', '/', '0', '1', '/', '2', '0', '2', '0', '2', '1', '/', '0', '1', '/', '2', '0', '2', '0'...
```

I see that this is happening because I've used `try` however if I don't I get an error
Also, **is there a better way to insert this data into a SQL database?** other than `extend` it into a list and itinarate over that list later on in order to insert it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in `extend` when I should've `append` the lists.